# Capacitor-like-thing for controlling temperature of fluid?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, capacitance, insulators

I want to minimise the Gibbs' phenomenon like thing i.e. sudden peaks (temperature peaks here) in a container.
Assume you have a cone where you want to block the transmittance of the temperature into the cone like current by capacitors. 
The ideal situation would be that the material by which the cone is made contains naturally things like capacitors. 
However, I have not seen such a material and so small capacitors.

The other design is to have the cone surface insulator while at the ends of the cone to have things like capacitors to store heat (instead of electric charge) for fluid.

**Are there any things like capacitors for fluid in such a situation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual [hydraulic analogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy) for a capacitor is an elastic membrane:

[image: Hydraulic capacitor]

A capacitor doesn't allow current to flow across it, but you can push charge onto it by applying a potential. In the hydraulic analogy an elastic membrane across the pipe doesn't allow water to flow through it, but you can push some water through the pipe by elastically deforming the membrane.

Comment: How does this work for temperature in air coming outside to the container? Container is filled with water but outside is air with different amount of humidity.

Comment: @Masi: I must admit I didn't really grasp what you are proposing. Maybe you could draw a digram to illustrate your experimental setup.

Comment: Your proposal is promising. There is a container which is full of water and supported frictionlessly. The heat is coming from the surrounding environment into the cone - from the two ends of the cone. I think your proposal can work also for a membrane separating air and water